# SQL - SELECT * FROM database.table ORDER BY uit asc

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEBwJ.png)I would like to SELECT from a table where column uit consist value from 20 to 100 included. please find the attached pic as an example. After select by uit column, it will show the highlighted portion only (included "index", "index_","sales","return" and other 300+ columns)

for example: SELECT * FROM database.table ORDER BY or where...

Thank you very much!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkDUi.png)

Comment: It would help if you spent supplied a text version of your dataset not a screenshot.

Comment: Why are some of the rows with uit=5 highlighted and some not?

Comment: sorry, I updated the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  database.table
WHERE
  "uit " BETWEEN 20
  AND 100
```

> The BETWEEN operator is inclusive: begin and end values are included - [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp#:%7E:text=The%20BETWEEN%20operator%20selects%20values,and%20end%20values%20are%20included.)

Comment: Hi RobMac, thank you for your help. I actually have more than 300 columns, it’s impossible to select  by typing “index”, “index_”, “sales”, “return”, ….+ 300 columns. Could you please let me know how to proceed? Thank you so much!

Comment: Instead of doing a multiselect by 
' ""index",
  "index_",
  "sales",
  "return"'"
replace it with '*' this symbol means, 'get all'. In your's case: 


SELECT * WHERE
  "uit " BETWEEN 20
  AND 100